# Datatables Server-side processing with IXR_Library

Tags: php, datatables, xml-rpc

I am using IXR_Library for making XML-RPC request to server. And the problem is I am getting a huge   amount data from the server and if I want to display them in datatable it processes very very slow. That't why I decided to use " Server-side processing " but this feature works with database. How can I implement this feature with XML-RPC?

PS : I am getting array and I encoded to JSONa also.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you use paging to limit the amount of data returned?

Comment: @markpsmith I got the data as an array from the server but I couldn't display it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Unless there's an alternative to getting ALL the data in one go, I'm not use you can use datatables in this way. Is there any filtering that5 you can apply?

Comment: Actually I have a huge amount of data and If I want to display these data it loads very very slow, that's why I am using server side processing, the question is how can I use already gotten data as an array and display?